# Pandas query is inconsistent

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I need to calculate a sum in python based on a huge json file. It is of importance that the calculation is correct. First I add it to pandas and it gets a structure like the following, but bigger.

```
A B
a 1
a 2
b 2
```

Then I want the sum of column B where A is a. To do this I use the pandas query method. The problem is that sometimes it gives the correct answer, 3, and sometimes just 0. I have tried both of the code syntaxes below, which I think is equivalent to each other.

```py
my_sum = df[df["A"] == "a"].sum()["B"]
my_sum = df.query("A == 'a'")['B'].sum()
```

Could it be the query that is run asynchronously?

How can this sum be calculated without getting any inconsistencies?

Clearifications:

my_sum sometimes equals 3
but most often
my_sum equals 0

It is more often 3 when running in the pycharm debugger.
Column B consists of floats.

Comment: Notice the difference `df.loc[df['A']=='a', 'B'].sum()` and `df[df['A']=='a'].sum()['B']`, the latter sum on all columns and extract `'B'`, which is more expensive.

Comment: Dont use `sum` or any keywords as variables.

Comment: what do you mean by this? `Then I want the sum of column B where A is 1.` I cant see any 1 in A column. Also can you please indicate which statement is giving 0 in your case?

Comment: If `query` were inconsistent, you'd see a difference between `my_sum` with the above two methods. But you haven't made it at all clear that this is the case: "it gives the correct answer, 3, and sometimes just 0". This indicates that there's a problem with your data, not that query is giving a different result from `loc`. You probably have leading/trailing whitespace that way though you think the value is `'a'` it's really `'   a'` so you're summing an empty DataFrame which gives 0. Look at `df.A.unique()`

Comment: @QuangHoang That was helpful, thank you. I will consider that when optimising further.

Comment: @ALollz If the dataframe really was empty, how come it gives me a correct answer at some times, and then when rerunning the exact code, it gives 0?

Comment: Because you're probably not running the **exact** same code. You probably accidentally modify `df` somewhere and don't realize. I can run that code 1M times and I get 3 every time. You need to provide a [mcve] otherwise this is all just guesswork as to what error you made that we can't see.

Comment: Yeah, I am simplifying the code because I am not allowed to publish production data. The concept is the same, but there is about 20 columns and thousands of rows. Could be that the internal memory runs out?

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that you are modifying the dataframe

Comment: How could the data frames be changed during two runs of the same unittests? It's the same json file, same insertion method, same unittests. It doesn't make sense to me. I would love some clarification.

Comment: There is no way anyone can tell without a [mcve].